-Dhttp.proxyHost and proxy settings being ignored by java
Java spring boot with feign is ignoring proxy settings.  Starting the app like this:
"C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-8\bin\java.exe" -DproxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=58189:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath603637298.jar com.me.myproj.Main

When the feign client calls a 3rd party service in ignores the proxy settings (Charles proxy in my case) and goes direct.
NOTE: its spring boot 2.0.3 and java 8
@EnableFeignClients
@FeignClient(value="some-api", url="${client.some-api}")
public interface SomeApi {
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/someurl", consumes = "application/json")
    public String getSomething(@PathVariable("eventId") String eventId);
}


our application.yml looks like this:
feign:
  client:
    config:
      default:
        connectTimeout: ${FEIGN_CONNECT_TIMEOUT:180000}
        readTimeout: ${FEIGN_READ_TIMEOUT:180000}
        loggerLevel: full

pom.xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


I checked the feign.Client class and the connection is created only like this
connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(request.url()).openConnection();

However, to get a connection through a proxy, you need to use the URL.openConnection(Proxy proxy) method. Since there is no such option for creating a connection in this library, I believe that there is no way to use a proxy in Spring Cloud OpenFeign 2.0.0.RELEASE.

I found the answer, and its a bit embarrassing.  The answer was this:
 -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8888

I assumed -Dhttp would do both, and the samples I found online all used the http version.
